# performing operations on sql table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am learning sql and I have a created a table

`products`  which has a columns `item`,`price`, `base`, `wholesale`

What I am trying to achieve is have a Number input by user (suppose user enters  15). Then it means they want to increase the prices of all 3 columns (price, base and wholesale) by 15%.

This is my input and submit button

```
<html>
<head><title>Product table</title></head>
<body>
<form>
Enter the percentage increment:
   <input type="number" name="inc">
   <input type="submit" value="Increment" id="Increment" name="Increment">
<?php
if($_REQUEST['Increment']=='Increment') {
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","test","pwd","db")or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));      

    $sql="SELECT 'price' from products"; 
  $result = $conn->query($sql) or die("Error in the query..." .mysqli_error($conn));
   // $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $inc = $_REQUEST['inc'];
    $incmod = $inc/100;


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $sql1="update products set price = ($row['price']-($row['price']*$incmod))";
    $conn->query($sql1) or die("Error in the query..." .mysqli_error($conn));
  }
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I tried to do but did not work. Is there any way to fix this? I know there are some obvious mistakes like $_REQUEST['inc], and Update statement but I am not able to do it right. Also I am still learning the transition form mysql to mysqli so maybe there are some errors in the syntax too.

**What happens when I execute the above code: Nothing happens. The table does not update with new values. It stays as it is. No errors appear**

**NOTE:** All sorts of criticism is welcome since it is my learning point. But also please give reason for downvotes so I can ask better questions

As per suggestions I have reduced the code to remove the unwanted lines of code. Here is the new code

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<br/>
Enter the percentage increment:
<input type="number" name="inc" id="inc" >
<input type="submit" value="Increment" id="Increment" name="Increment">
<br/>
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['Increment'])) {
$inc = $_REQUEST['inc'];
$incmod = $inc/100;
    echo "true";
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","test","pwd","db")or die("Error in the query..." .mysqli_error($conn));

  $mysqli->query("UPDATE products SET price=price+(price*$incmod), baseprice=baseprice+(baseprice*$incmod), wholesale=wholesale+(36months*$incmod)");


   $mysqli->close();
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for all the input. Somehow $incmod was not printing anything. I tried a few things suggested here and created a fresh php page. Finally the variables started getting the value from the input type and the code is working fine.

Comment: You need to use single (or double) quotes in PHP, *not* backticks. `$sql1="update products set price = ($row['price']-($row['price']*$incmod))";`

Comment: Your SQL command seems to be incorrect, it should be `$sql="SELECT 'price' from products";` .Either way, why are you executing this query?

Comment: You are completely missing the body tag, first of all. You have  a syntax error in your sql query, delete the comma after `price`.

Comment: I updated the question with the changes suggested.

Comment: No no, for table and column names you need to use backticks, since it's MySQL.

Comment: @SatejS Im getting all the values from the column price and then run through the loop to perform percentage calculation on each row and update the price column. Is it not required you think? Can you elaborate what query I should use instead of this one?

Comment: why not do thi calculation before calling the query... and then just need to pass in 1 variable: $row['price']-($row['price']*$incmod

Comment: Also tell us what tells you it isn't working. An error message? blank page? nothing inserted? etc.

Comment: @Andrew I added a line above Note to make it bit clear as to what happens

Comment: To help with debugging, print out echo statements for echo-ing the received value from the user input onto the page.This will make sure the value is being received in PHP. Also where is `$result` being defined?

Comment: @SatejS I forgot to add $result. Just added it. I will echo the value and tell you what comes up in a minute

Comment: echo does not echo anything. The page redirects to a default page that I have on clicking submit and the update sql statement is having problem. If I comment out update statement then the html code shows up otherwise it disappears.

Comment: And the file is saved with a .php extension, right?

Comment: It does have .php extension

Comment: Echo should print everything, this means there are some values missing. 1. Was the echo printing the inc value from the form? 2. For ease, perform the updation operation in a variable above the SQL1 command, and print this out.

Comment: Okay, I am not sure if that is the problem, but it is clear that you are mixing the procedural and object oriented style. Instead of $conn-> query, use mysqli_query () and send the link and query to mysql server. See if it helps.

Comment: I'll try it out and tell you what happened

Comment: Or better, replace the mysqli_connect () with new mysqli ()

Comment: if(isset($_REQUEST['Increment'])) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","test","pwd","db");
        
      $mysqli->query("UPDATE products SET price=price+(price*$incmod), base=base+(base*$incmod), wholesale=wholesale+(wholesale*$incmod)");
       $mysqli->close();
}

Comment: @Devashish is this the correct way?

Comment: Looks like it's okay. Why don't you try it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101741/discussion-between-shrilekha-and-devashish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes because of which it does not work. The main one, probably, is that you try to fetch array from the $result, while you never set this $result.

Beside this, you don't need the select query at all here. You can increase/decrease all prices at once in a single update query:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE products SET price=price+(price*$incmod), base=base+(base*$incmod), wholesale=wholesale+(wholesale*$incmod)";
    $conn->query($sql) or die("Error in the query..." .mysqli_error($conn));
```

Also, I would suggest to test the form submission by existence of the variable rather by its value:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['Increment'])){ ...
```

UPDATE:
You have no output because there is a fatal syntax error, and your PHP environment is probably set to not show errors. The error is on this line:

```
    $sql1="update products set price = ($row['price']-($row['price']*$incmod))";
```

You don't need to use a single quotes for array keys inside a double-quoted string. The row could be:

```
    $sql1="update products set price = ($row[price]-$row[price]*$incmod))";
```

But, as I mentioned before, you don't need the whole loop here. Actually, if it would work, it would update the whole table (all rows) multiple times (the same times as the number of rows in this table). You just need one single update query. No fetch, no loop, just one exec.

P.S. Sorry for not continuing your discussion in comments instead of posting an answer, but I can not comment, since it demands 50 reputation, and I had 21.

Comment: What you've written as an answer here, everyone has been commenting above.Please read the same before answering.

Comment: I'll try out the if statement and other suggestions and get back to you

Comment: @Shrilekha and I don't think it would help.

Comment: I tried there is still some error. I mean I cannot see what the error is but it does not perform the operation. But thank you for trying

Comment: Also I removed while loop as recommended by everyone and also removed the select statement

Comment: Well the solution along with the changes told by @Devashish and Satej S worked after trying a few times.

Answer (score 0):

here is you solution

while you **Select** the record

```
$sql="SELECT price from products";
```

remove the single quote

and your calculation write like this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $re=$row['price'] - ($row['price'] * $incmod);
  echo $re."<bR>";
  $sql1="update products set price =".$re;  
  $conn->query($sql1) or die("Error in the query..." .mysqli_error($conn));
  }
```

Comment: I'll give it a go and let you know.

Comment: I'll tell you by tomorrow as it is time for me to sign off my work.